# why pr2-controllers use a shared pointer + realtimebox?

Tags: ros, real-time, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

As I further explore controllers, I notice that shared access is made possible by a realtimebox containing a shared pointer.
If I understand correctly, the realtimebox uses a mutex for thread safety. However the shared pointer, too, offers multiple access protection.
This seems redundant to me. Maybe I'm missing something ? Why is it done this way ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9946/why-pr2-controllers-use-a-shared-pointer-+-realtimebox-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guido,

Some uses of `boost::shared_ptr` are thread safe, but other uses are not.

The [documentation for shared pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) describes which operations are thread safe:

> A shared_ptr instance can be "read" (accessed using only const operations) simultaneously by multiple threads. Different shared_ptr instances can be "written to" (accessed using mutable operations such as operator= or reset) simultaneosly by multiple threads (even when these instances are copies, and share the same reference count underneath.)

These are the two things you can do with a shared pointer: access it without changing it and modify separate shared pointer instances simultaneously.  The realtime box solves a third use case: passing an instance of a shared pointer from one thread to another.

Consider the following scenario.  Two threads share a global shared pointer named `ptr`.  Thread A writes to `ptr`, and thread B reads from it:

=== Thread A

ptr.reset(new Object);

=== Thread B

my_ptr = ptr;

This is not guaranteed to be thread safe because shared pointer assignment is not atomic.  The assignment to `my_ptr` can occur at the same time that thread A is modifying `ptr`, leading to a corrupted shared pointer.

If you're still doubtful, here is a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692438/is-boost-shared-ptr-xxx-thread-safe) with a similar example.

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-06-06**:
So that's what I was missing :). Thanks for the answer.